# How to assign keys to items in a column in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have the following RDD:

```
 Col1     Col2
"abc"    "123a"
"def"    "783b"
"abc     "674b"
"xyz"    "123a"
"abc"    "783b"
```

I need the following output where each item in each column is converted into a unique key. 
`for example : abc->1,def->2,xyz->3`

```
Col1      Col2
1          1
2          2
1          3
3          1
1          2
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can rely on the hashCode of the string. The hashcode will be the same if the input and datatype is same. Try this.

```
scala> "abc".hashCode
res23: Int = 96354

scala> "xyz".hashCode
res24: Int = 119193

scala> val df = Seq(("abc","123a"),
     | ("def","783b"),
     | ("abc","674b"),
     | ("xyz","123a"),
     | ("abc","783b")).toDF("col1","col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string]

scala>

scala> def hashc(x:String):Int =
     | return x.hashCode
hashc: (x: String)Int

scala> val myudf = udf(hashc(_:String):Int)
myudf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.select(myudf('col1), myudf('col2)).show
+---------+---------+
|UDF(col1)|UDF(col2)|
+---------+---------+
|    96354|  1509487|
|    99333|  1694000|
|    96354|  1663279|
|   119193|  1509487|
|    96354|  1694000|
+---------+---------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must map your columns into `natural numbers` starting from 1, one approach would be to apply `zipWithIndex` to the individual columns, add 1 to the index (as `zipWithIndex` always starts from 0), convert indvidual RDDs to DataFrames, and finally join the converted DataFrames for the index keys:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("abc", "123a"),
  ("def", "783b"),
  ("abc", "674b"),
  ("xyz", "123a"),
  ("abc", "783b")
))

val df1 = rdd.map(_._1).distinct.zipWithIndex.
  map(r => (r._1, r._2 + 1)).
  toDF("col1", "c1key")

val df2 = rdd.map(_._2).distinct.zipWithIndex.
  map(r => (r._1, r._2 + 1)).
  toDF("col2", "c2key")

val dfJoined = rdd.toDF("col1", "col2").
  join(df1, Seq("col1")).
  join(df2, Seq("col2"))
// +----+----+-----+-----+
// |col2|col1|c1key|c2key|
// +----+----+-----+-----+
// |783b| abc|    2|    1|
// |783b| def|    3|    1|
// |123a| xyz|    1|    2|
// |123a| abc|    2|    2|
// |674b| abc|    2|    3|
//+----+----+-----+-----+

dfJoined.
  select($"c1key".as("col1"), $"c2key".as("col2")).
  show
// +----+----+
// |col1|col2|
// +----+----+
// |   2|   1|
// |   3|   1|
// |   1|   2|
// |   2|   2|
// |   2|   3|
// +----+----+
```

Note that if you're okay with having the keys start from 0, the step of `map(r => (r._1, r._2 + 1))` can be skipped in generating `df1` and `df2`.